# Google Analytics - report full stackTrace of uncaught Exception

Tags: android, exception, google-analytics

I use this code to create a Tracker:

```
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Tracker myTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.track);
myTracker.set("&uid", appId);
myTracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
```

In track.xml I have:

```
<resources>
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-***</string>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resources>
```

This sends just the first line of the stack trace to Analytics.

How can I send the whole stack trace?

In [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions#overview) it says

> Warning: Never send the exception message (such as e.getMessage()) to
>   Google Analytics as it may contain personally identifiable
>   information.

Is it allowed to send the full stack trace?